# Unable to filter RACSignal events

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

My ViewController contains a UISearchBar and implements the UISearchBarDelegate protocol. I've created a signal for `searchBartextDidChange:` that fires correctly with `subscribeNext`:

```
RACSignal *searchTextChangeSignal = [self rac_signalForSelector:@selector(searchBar:textDidChange:) fromProtocol:@protocol(UISearchBarDelegate)];

[searchTextChangeSignal subscribeNext:^(id x){
  // This works.
}];
```

At this point, I'd like to filter the results of this filter to 1) Only include text that is greater than 3 characters, and 2) throttled by 300 ms. My attempt:

````
[[searchTextChangeSignal filter:^(RACTuple *tuple) {
  NSString *textEnteredIntoSearchBar = (NSString *)tuple.second;
  return textEnteredIntoSearchBar.length > 3;
}] throttle:300];```
````

The code above doesn't work. The blocks are never executed. If I replace the `filter` method with `subscribeNext`, the `subscribeNext` block *does* execute. Furthermore, XCode autocompletes the `filter` method above, so the method is available. Is there something I'm missing here? What's the correct way to do this? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing understanding is that signals do not perform any work until they are subscribed to. Call one of the subscribe methods following the throttle, and you will see the data start to flow through.

Comment: Thanks, David. This simple fact appears to be missing from the Reactive Cocoa documentation.

Comment: A quick look and it doesn't seem to be mentioned in the README, which is definitely an oversight. It is mentioned in the BasicOperators.md document. https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/Documentation/BasicOperators.md#performing-side-effects-with-signals